# php symfony 1 update generator.yml

Tags: php, symfony1

Is there a way to update generator.yml? I want to add a delete option for the list but nothing happened. Can someone help me? Also I tried hide or anything else. No matter wat I change in dis file it doesnt change on live. But dis file generates that site becuz templates just do extra things for the site.

```
    generator:
  class: sfDoctrineGenerator
  param:
    model_class:           UserDocument
    theme:                 custom_theme
    non_verbose_templates: true
    with_show:             false
    singular:              ~
    plural:                ~
    route_prefix:          user_document
    with_doctrine_route:   true
    actions_base_class:    sfActions

    config:
      actions: ~
      fields:  ~
      list:
        display:
          - _user_profile_id
          - _doc_type
          - =doc_value
          #- doc_expired_at
          #- updated_at
        batch_actions: []
        object_actions: []
        actions: []
      filter:
        class: BackendUserDocumentFormFilter
      form:
        class: BackendUserDocumentForm
        actions:
          _save: ~
      edit:    ~
      new:     ~
```

Comment: so nobody can answer?

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: how can I clear it?

Comment: In a terminal, go to project dir and execute `./symfony cc`

Comment: is there a way to clear cache for a specific module?

Comment: I dont think so. You can check the clear-cache command script to see how it works 
`~/web/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/task/cache/sfCacheClearTask.class.php`